# Extracting Information From CSV & XLSX to Display on HTML

Tags: html, excel

I am trying to figure out how to extract information from CSV & XLSX files.

My sheets would only have 1 column, one with numbers and letters.

But i need to extract them and then display them.

I have no clue how to do either.

Tried looking up in Google and in YouTube for the information, but am failing to find the right answer.

Comment: I assume File->Save As->Web Page file type doesn't help?

Comment: unfortunately, it would be something that is being uploaded to the website with a drag and drop option on the website

Comment: This is really far too broad for a site like this.